# Privilege used by MoveFileEx()

Tags: privilege, movefileex

When calling MoveFileEx() and using MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT for dwFlags.
During the actual moving of file what privilege does it use?

Thanks Kazuo!

Answer (score 2):

Th MSDN doesn't really say anything about this special situtation, but the hint "This value can be used only if the process is in the context of a user who belongs to the administrators group or the LocalSystem account." gives the only logic result that the Administrator privileges will be used to move the file (since the account that called this API might not be there).

Comment: Plus it reading between the lines this occurs during boot, pretty early, before anyone is logged in.  And the fact that it doesn't store any account information in the registry says it's probably the System account.